# WPF - What's the interest of dependency property without callback

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I don't understand the interest of a dependency property without callback defined.

Comment: [Dependency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: DPs are integrated with the XAML framework.  If a XAML element binds to a DP, it will get notified when the property changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A callback is just an added convenience -- dependency properties are integrated into the framework runtime, and have a built-in callback mechanism that updates any bindings.  That is, if you set a binding with a dependency property as the source, then the target will update automatically when the dependency property changes.

For example, let's say you have a custom control with a DP defined:

```
public string SomeDP
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(SomeDPProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SomeDPProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeDPProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SomeDP", typeof(string), typeof(SomeFrameworkElement), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

And if you set up a binding with the DP as the source for a TextBlock's "Text" property:

```
<local:SomeFrameworkElement x:Name="someFrameworkElement" SomeDP="initial" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=someFrameworkElement,Path=SomeDP}" />
```

Then whenever "someFrameworkElement"'s "SomeDP" property changes, the text will also change.